# Sending email from email gather through google forms using google script

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey I have a form setup to grab the user's email address then when they submit it a google sheet gathers all the information and a script runs.  I am sending out several emails with information gathered from the form but I am trying to make this email be sent from their account not mine since I have the form in my drive.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Code in GAS that performs email tasks will always be sent from the user that authorized the code. I have run into the same problem before and have not yet found a solution or ability to reset current user based on the sheet data and have that account run the code.